# Javascript prompt will not populate after writing first if statement

Tags: javascript

doing a school lesson where i have to get a javascript prompt to ask for a number grade that spits out a lettergrade. They prefilled the start of the script and I only need to do the if and else if statements. When I write my first if statement that pop up box/prompt doesn't come up anymore on my browser. this is my code.. what am I doing wrong? the school mentors are offline for help and I got hours to turn in..

```
var inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:");

var numberGrade = parseInt(inputGrade);

var letterGrade;



// Add your code below
if(numberGrade is >=90){
  letterGrade = "A";
}
else if(numberGrade is >=80){
  letterGrade = "B";
}
else if(numberGrade is >=70){
  letterGrade = "C";
}
else if (numberGrade is >=60){
  letterGrade = "D";
}
else (letterGrade){
  letterGrade = "F";
}

alert(letterGrade);
```

Comment: Don't include the word `is` in your if statements.

Comment: You will definitely want to learn to inspect errors thrown in your browser dev tools console. First place to look when something doesn't work. The messages will tell you what and where

Comment: F12 key will open it most browsers. If error occurs in your page code it will appear there. Lots of other valuable tools there also. Search "<browserName> dev tools" for documentation, videos etc. Also documentation links in the toolbar

Comment: The last else also contains an error: else(letterGrade) should be else {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `is` from each statement, and then just have a final `else` instead of `else (letterGrade)`.

```js
var inputGrade = prompt("Enter a grade:");

var numberGrade = parseInt(inputGrade);

var letterGrade;

if (numberGrade >= 90) {
  letterGrade = "A";
} else if (numberGrade >= 80) {
  letterGrade = "B";
} else if (numberGrade >= 70) {
  letterGrade = "C";
} else if (numberGrade >= 60) {
  letterGrade = "D";
} else {
  letterGrade = "F";
}

alert(letterGrade);
```

Comment: Forgot to remove that IS from the copy and paste. Dont know where I got that from lol,
Seriously thanks though. after removing the (letterGrade) after else it all worked.